# Remove Youtube Annotations from mediaelement.js Player?

Tags: javascript, youtube, mediaelement.js

I have tried adding &iv_load_policy=3 to the end of the YouTube url in multiple ways, but the annotations still show. Is there any way to edit the code so that no annotations will show?

**EDIT: CODE BELOW**

Files from the [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) Plugin

Random Video with Annotations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGz13x5OJ_8

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelementplayer.css" />

<script>
$(function(){
   player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video-player');
});
</script>

<video style="width:100%;height:100%;" id="video-player" preload="preload" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGz13x5OJ_8" />   
</video>
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are using? Could you provide a link to a youtube video with annotations?

Comment: @JFK Original question has been updated. I tried editing mediaelement-and-player.js to add &iv_load_policy=3 in a way, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. This http://jsfiddle.net/K5cY9/ with your exact code doesn't show any annotations (Firefox and Chrome). In what conditions you get the annotations? OS? browser? can you create a fiddle or demo to reproduce it?

Comment: @JFK On Your jsFiddle, I see no annotations in Chrome with Mavericks, but I see them in IE with Windows 7.

But with the same code on my website, I am seeing annotations in all scenarios. I can't see anything that you changed that would remove annotations. Perhaps jsFiddle has some internal YouTube settings?

Comment: I know what was happening with the jsfiddle: it was using MEJS v2.8.2 (as in MEJS demos) and the annotations weren't showing. I updated it to a newer version (v2.13.2) and the annotations show up in all browsers http://jsfiddle.net/K5cY9/1/ ... that's a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found to suppress YouTube annotations is setting MEJS' YouTube plugin instead of flash (default) like :

```
$(function () {
    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video-player', {
        plugins: ['youtube']
    });
});
```

The only inconvenience is that `autoplay` doesn't work (haven't found the option yet) but at least the main issue is solved  ;)

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zE26G/)**

Comment: Thank you! That solves the problem. The play() or load() methods don't seem to make the video play right away, so there must be something that the player is doing onclick to initialize YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

The embedded player is the flash version.

According to the youtube player API, only the html5 and AS3 players support this option: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#iv_load_policy

You can embed this through an iframe, and it will embed the html5 player and work, for example:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/IGz13x5OJ_8?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&autoplay=1&html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The &html5=1 is only to force html5 if possible, though if the video supports it, it should use html5 by default anyway.

Comment: Also, I don't believe it's currently supported by youtube to embed the html5 video using video tags. Go figure.

Comment: I already tried this and it works well for desktop browsers, but the problem is that the video will not play on mobile (inside the mediaelement.js player).

Comment: then there's a problem with the mediaelement.js library.
It's clearly supported by youtube, and one of the reasons they made the html5 players to begin with.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference